# How to check if mock has any side effects left?

Tags: python, python-mock

In python, is it possible to check if there are any and how many side effects are remaining?

For example:

```
mocked_foo = patch.object(Foo, 'method', side_effects=[1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 0):

This reads the number of digits in the variable.

```
n=int(input(mocked_foo))
count=0
while(n>0):
    count=count+1
    n=n//10
print("The number of side effects left are:",count)
```

Comment: Won't this remove all the remaining side effects?

Comment: All this is doing is counting the numbers in it, The variables N and Mocked_Foo are still the same